# TSQL Not Equal <> behaving differently

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2

```
TABLE1 - Column DateCreated datetime null
TABLE2 - Column DateCreated datetime null

When I see the profiler
SELECT * from TABLE1
WHERE DateCreated <> '2011-06-10 00:00:00.000'
```

I have 3 records for this date

```
2011-06-10 00:00:00.000
2011-06-10 00:00:00.000
2011-06-10 09:45:00.000
```

None of the records are returned

On TABLE2

```
SELECT * from TABLE2
WHERE DateCreated <> '2011-06-10 00:00:00.000'
```

I have 3 records for this date

```
2011-06-10 18:02:05.000
2011-06-10 18:05:08.000
2011-06-10 18:07:09.000
```

All 3 records are returned. This is very weird. Why in the 1st case do I not get back any records when I should get 1 record back???

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e3f5/1/1

Comment: Can you try to do the following before the query: set dateformat ymd

Comment: Tried that Agnius but doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL, '2011-06-10 00:00:00.000' is not a date. It is a string that gets converted to a date. In the database '2011-06-10 00:00:00.000' might actually be '2011-06-10 00:00:00.00001'. Maybe try using DATEDIFF(mcs,DateCreated,'2011-06-10 00:00:00.000') to see what the actual difference is.

Comment: SqlServer uses a resolution of about 3 milliseconds (with last digit a 0, 3 or 7), so that particular date-string should be converted exactly.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what datediff(mcs provides then

Comment: I cant use datediff as I am using Dynamic Linq which generates these sql queries which I am pasting from SQL Profiler

Comment: Cannot you just copy the SQL from the profiler, edit it and run via query analyser (or SSMS)?

Comment: Yes.. but add the datediff to the query. Something like:

SELECT *, datediff(mcs, '2011-06-10 00:00:00.000', DateCreated) from TABLE1
WHERE DateCreated between '2011-06-09 23:59:00.000' and '2011-06-10 00:01:00.000'

Comment: I cant becusing my code base using Dynamic Linq. In SQL Server it works. problem is Linq. Field name are dynamically used to build the query.